# Não consigo fazer um backup do banco mysql usando o dump

Tags: mysql

estou com algumas duvidas. Eu preciso fazer uma cópia de um banco de dados que não está na minha maquina, e sim em um servidor.. estou usando o comando dump do mysql, porém quando eu digito o seguinte comando

mysqldump -u usuario -senha&1234 obanco > arquivo.sql

, ele retorna que o que esta a partir do "&", não é valido..

assim:

"1234 não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo ou um programa operável  ou um arquivo em lotes".

esse "&" na senha não pode existir? ...

mais uma coisa, antes de usar este comando eu preciso me conectar ao banco certo?

prompt> mysql [-h nome_maquina ou ip] [-u nome_usuario] [-psua_senha]

eu utilizo este comando?..

agradecido desde de já.

Comment: O dump se executa direto no console. E o problema não está no dump, mas na falta de escapar os caracteres especiais. Se for linux, experimente com uma \ antes do &

Comment: Utililze **Toad for MySQL** (http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/1469) é muito útil para trabalhar de manutenção, fazer backup é bem prático.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robson, abra seu prompt de comando e navegue até a pasta onde está o executável do seu **mysqldump**, provavelmente na pasta **bin** do MySqlServer.

**Exemplo:**

```
cd\
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
```

**Execute o comando do mysqldump para realizar o backup:**

```
mysqldump -h ip_servidor -p porta_servidor -u usuario -p senha_usuario nome_banco > backup.sql
```

Você não precisa do '&' na senha, a não ser que sua senha seja composta por ele.

Substitua 'ip_servidor' pelo endereço correspondente do seu servidor, bem como os campos 'porta_servidor', 'usuario', 'senha_usuario' e nome_banco.

Comment: valeu amigo, funcionou.

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha funcionado Robson, por favor, selecione como resposta para que outros usuários também vejam.

Answer (score 0):

Se vc estiver na mesma máquina onde está o banco:

```
mysqldump -uUser -pSenha DataBase > c:\seu_backup.sql
```

Se vc estiver em outra máquina (que possua o mysql instalado) e esteja na mesma rede que o banco:

`mysqldump -uUser -pSenha -hIp_do_Banco DataBase > c:\seu_backup.sq`l

Obs.: SO Windows

Comment: valeu amigo, consegui.